# Basic CSS / layout issue - dynamic columns?

Tags: html, css, layout, portlet, freemarker

I have a really simple CSS question, but I would like to know the "best" way to solve it.

I have two tables. I want it so that if they can both fit next to each other on a page (the screen / window is wide enough), that they will show up side by side. Otherwise, I just want it so they are on different rows.

What is the proper way to solve this issue with CSS (or something else)?

(Note: I am creating creating a portlet for uPortal 4. But any general answers will help)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Put each table in a `<div>` and style the `<div>` containers `float: left`

Answer (score 0):

You can even style the `table` element without `div` elements. Use `float:left` to make them sit side to side.

```
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>
            Hi
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

      <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>
            Hi
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

table{
float:left;
width:200px;
height:200px;
font-size:2em;
font-family:helvetica;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/F3F5L/)